# Using <% asp tags in javascript not working?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I can't get the following to work:

`var percent = <% Model.Percent; %>`

I am sending a Model to the view from the controller...I'm getting the error:

`Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Am I being extremely stupid?

Comment: +1 for asking a coherent question, and providing a relevant exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
var percent = <% Model.Percent; %>
```

With:

```
var percent = <%= Model.Percent %>
```

The `<%` nugget simply means, "run this code as a C# statement".  It doesn't actually render any value.  `<%=` on the other hand evaluates the C# expression, and converts it to a string and renders it.  This way, it'll print out the percent in your javascript.